# Complex condition and returned value using xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm using xpath in order to get values from xml. I found a particular situation:

```
<Docs>
    <Doc>
       <tag1>0</tag1>
       <tag2>150.0</tag2>
    </Doc>
    <Doc>
       <tag1>45</tag1>
       <tag2>0</tag2>
    </Doc>
</Docs>
```

There are two posibilities for each Doc entity:

**case 1:** if (`tag1` = 0 and `tag2` != 0) or (tag2 = 0 and tag1 != 0), I need to return the non-zero value.

**case 2:** Maybe the two fields are 0. I need to return 0

**UPDATE1:**
For example:
Suppose that I query the first node Doc (/Docs/doc[0]). I need to get 150.0. For the second one (/Docs/doc[1]) I need to get 45.

How can I solve this using just xpath?

Comment: And what's if both non-zero?

Comment: @splash58 it won't happen in my specific problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a great and readable solution:

```
Docs/Doc/*[starts-with(name(), 'tag') and .!=0][1]/text()
```

Comment: What about case 2?

Answer (score 1):

Simple **xpath** expression:

```
//Doc/*[text() != '0']/text()
```

XPath result:

```
150.0
45
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the xpath union (|) operator, in order to cover all cases:

```
Docs/Doc[tag1=0]/tag2[.!=0]/text() | 
Docs/Doc[tag2=0]/tag1[.!=0]/text() | 
Docs/Doc[tag1=0 and tag2=0]/tag1/text()
```